# Apache Ignite: Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception

Tags: nio, ignite

I recently get this error every time when I try to load around 100G data into ignite. (Actually is around 50G, with one backup for this cache). Typically this error happens after it successfully loaded 2/3 data into the ignite cluster, and somehow one of 3 nodes starts to throw these 2 error messages all the time, while the pod does not crush and restart because we give enough memory and cpu, so this node just keep throwing errors, until my loading task reaches timeout, and the node left the topolgy.

```
[19:01:08,637][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-1-#1016][TcpCommunicationSpi] Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception.
```

```
class org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioException: null
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2538)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2287)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1909)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gridgain.control.agent.dto.tracing.Span.writeTo(Span.java:248)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.direct.stream.v2.DirectByteBufferStreamImplV2.writeMessage(DirectByteBufferStreamImplV2.java:687)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.direct.stream.v3.DirectByteBufferStreamImplV3.write(DirectByteBufferStreamImplV3.java:210)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.direct.stream.v2.DirectByteBufferStreamImplV2.writeRandomAccessList(DirectByteBufferStreamImplV2.java:791)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.direct.stream.v2.DirectByteBufferStreamImplV2.writeCollection(DirectByteBufferStreamImplV2.java:738)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.direct.DirectMessageWriter.writeCollection(DirectMessageWriter.java:317)
    at org.gridgain.control.agent.dto.tracing.SpanBatch.writeTo(SpanBatch.java:64)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.direct.stream.v2.DirectByteBufferStreamImplV2.writeMessage(DirectByteBufferStreamImplV2.java:687)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.direct.DirectMessageWriter.writeMessage(DirectMessageWriter.java:299)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoMessage.writeTo(GridIoMessage.java:209)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.writeToBuffer(GridNioServer.java:1788)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processWrite0(GridNioServer.java:1711)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processWrite(GridNioServer.java:1407)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2525)
    ... 4 more
```

Meanwhile, the other 2 ignite nodes simply shows "*Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues)*" and "*class org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterTopologyCheckedException: Failed to wait for establishing inverse connection (node left topology): 881b203c-f350-44b9-bb4c-0b90a48eaccf*"

When data size is small, there's no such issue.

Comment: Hello, could you please let me know what version of the Control Center agent you are using? And what version of the Ignite/GridGain too.

Comment: I use gridgain community version 8.8.19, and control center uses 2022.3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed as part of the GridGain 8.8.25 release as far as I know.

Please upgrade your GridGain Community Edition from 8.8.19 to 8.8.25+ versions.

Regards,
Andrei